# Javascript dropdown / select, focused value (not selected)

Tags: javascript, select

Is there a way in JS, in a `<SELECT>`, to get the value of the `<OPTION>` ...

which is :

- currently focused (i mean the select is opened, and the option is colored by either mouse hovering, either keyboard use (choice by arrows),
- but not validated (so the select value, or the select selectedindex option value are not the good answer)

Tried googling without success. Thank you,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think in order to focus, you'd have to click on it, which means it's selected. But maybe try using a hover event.

Comment: Finally, i changed the way to do it. 
The wanted use is a selection of a sound in a list, so i added the tag size="X" to show multiple lines on the SELECT, and set on onchange event, my playsound() function to play the selected sample. The visual size allows an easier keyboard navigation (though the mouse use stills needs a click, not effect on hover).
Topic closed - Thanks to contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Hello LGD this might answer your question

```js
const select =document.getElementById('myselect')
let a = 1 //default value
select.addEventListener("change",()=>
    
    { a = select.value
        console.log(a)
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="mselect" id="myselect">
        <option value="1">select 1</option>
        <option value="2">select 2</option>
        <option value="3">select 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, this does noes solve the problem : the "onchange" event triggers when the select is "validated", which means closed by selecting a value (mouse or keyboard). 
I want an action to be done when the FOCUS on an option is done, i mean when i hover the option for exemple, but it could be done too with keyboard arrows, maybe some other ways. 
The action has to be done before the "value" change (so, the event "onchange" should not be useful here).

Comment: You very welcome. Ok I see. Maybe you Can try wrapping each options within a span tag and try with mouseover eventlistener and see if it works

Comment: I see, but it that case i would need to set some keyboard listeners too... This is really dirty, especially when the select contains about 100 options... I'm surprised javascript cannot handle the option "focus" event.